# How can I check file types with Vuelidate?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

How can I check file types (png,jpg,jpeg) with Vue.js Vuelidate library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **helpers** validator with regex check. More info [here](https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-optional-validator)

```
import { helpers, required } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

const imageRule = helpers.regex('image', /\.(gif|jpe?g|tiff|png)$/)

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            image: '',
        }
    },
    validations: {
        image: {
            required,
            imageRule
        },
    },
}
```